# No Class Def Found error for ElementListener

Tags: java, nokia, nokia-s40

I am testing an example java application on a Nokia 303 device using Nokia's java SDK/IDE(Eclipse). The example makes use of the categorybar and sets an element listener. When I run the app on the emulator, it works fine. When I run the app on the device however, I get the error:

No Class Def Found Error
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError
com/nokia/example/canvas/CanvasExample:com/nokia/mid/ui/ElementListener

What is missing here? The ElementListener should be part of the nokiaui library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say which version of the SDK you are using, but according to http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/Asha_303/ Developer Platform for this phone is "Series 40 Developer Platform 1.1".

Make sure you are using "Nokia SDK 1.1 for Java — for Series 40 apps" from http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Tools/